# Java AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater - ClassCastException when using generic types

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception, atomicreference

I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException
at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater$AtomicReferenceFieldUpdaterImpl.<init>(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:336)
at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.java:109)
at org.telegram.bot.util.FieldTimer.<init>(FieldTimer.java:27)
at org.telegram.bot.util.FieldTimer.<init>(FieldTimer.java:19)
at org.telegram.bot.util.FieldTimer.main(FieldTimer.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

when using `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` for generic types.

I'am totally confused and I have no idea why I'm getting such an error.

the code I am using :

```
public final class FieldTimer<V> {

    private volatile V value;
    private final V defaultValue;
    private final long resetTimeout;
    private final AtomicLong lastSet;
    private final AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater<FieldTimer, V> updater;

    public FieldTimer(V value, Class<V> type, long resetTimeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        this(value, value, type, resetTimeout, unit);
    }

    public FieldTimer(V value, V defaultValue, Class<V> type, long resetTimeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.resetTimeout = unit.toMillis(resetTimeout);
        lastSet = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());
        updater = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(FieldTimer.class, type, "value");
    }

    public V get() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSet.get() >= resetTimeout
                ? defaultValue
                : value;
    }

    public void set(V value) {
        updater.set(this, value);
        lastSet.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public boolean compareAndSet(V expect, V update) {
        boolean set = updater.compareAndSet(this, expect, update);
        if (set) {
            lastSet.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        return set;
    }

}
```

the exception occurs in this line of code :

```
updater = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(FieldTimer.class, type, "value");
```

but, if I change it to something like this :

```
public final class LongFieldTimer {

    private volatile Long value;

    ...

    public LongFieldTimer(Long value, Long defaultValue, long resetTimeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        ...
        updater = AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.newUpdater(LongFieldTimer.class, Long.class, "value");
    }

}
```

then there would be no errors :| (but why???)

what causes this problem? and how to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field

```
private volatile V value;
```

is of type `Object` because of [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). The javadoc of [`AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater#newUpdater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.html#newUpdater-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) states that it throws

> `ClassCastException` - if the field is of the wrong type

You've presumably passed `Long.class` or `long.class` as an argument for the `type` parameter. It expects `Object.class`.

In your second example, the field is explicitly defined as being of type `Long`

```
private volatile Long value;
```

so `Long.class` will work, since that is the type of the field expected.